# Prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln^{\delta}(x)}{x^{\varepsilon}}=0 $ for every $\delta\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon >0$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to show that the following limit is true for all $\delta\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon>0$:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln^{\delta}(x)}{x^{\varepsilon}}=0$$

I know that applying L'Hopital's rule $\lceil\delta\rceil$ times so that (disregarding constants):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln^{\delta}(x)}{x^{\varepsilon}}=\dots\sim\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x^\delta}}{x^{\varepsilon-\delta}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x^{\varepsilon}}=0$$

Is my proof valid? Is there a more direct proof without using L'Hopital?

Thank you.

Comment: $\ln^d(x)$ means $(\ln x)^d$, correct?

Comment: Yes. That's how we write it... :-)

Comment: The derivatives of the top get messy. Things may feel simpler if you let $y=\ln x$, then the top is just $y^{\delta}$, the bottom is $e^{\epsilon y}$.

Comment: By the way, I forgot to add, I found it quite interesting (and fascinating, perhaps) that $\sum\frac{1}{n\ln^{1+\delta}(n)} $converges for all $\delta>0$, while  $\sum\frac{1}{n^{1-\varepsilon}\ln^{\delta}(n)}$ diverges for all $\varepsilon>0$, $\delta\in\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you differentiate $\ln^{\delta}(x)$ with respect to $x$, you will get $\delta \dfrac{\ln^{\delta-1}(x)}{x}$ and not as what you have written. It is easier to do it directly, than use L'Hopital's rule.

Replacing $x$ by $\exp(t)$, we get that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\ln^{\delta}(x)}{x^{\varepsilon}} = \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{t^{\delta}}{\exp(\varepsilon t)}$$

Note that $$\exp(\varepsilon t) > \dfrac{(\varepsilon t)^n}{n!}$$ where $n$ is chosen so that it is greater than $\delta$. This is so since $\dfrac{(\varepsilon t)^n}{n!}$ is one term in the taylor expansion of $\exp(\varepsilon t)$ and all the other terms are also positive.

Now you get what you want since
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{t^{\delta}}{\exp(\varepsilon t)} <  \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{t^{\delta}}{\dfrac{(\varepsilon t)^n}{n!}} = \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n!}{\varepsilon^n} \dfrac1{t^{n - \delta}} = \frac{n!}{\varepsilon^n} \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac1{t^{n - \delta}} = 0$$

Comment: very nice. thx!

Comment: As per your first comment, I specifically mentioned "disregarding constants" and used ~, as opposed to =.

Answer (score 2):

Without L'Hopital:

- If $\delta\gt0$, one can use the identity
  $$
  \frac{\log^\delta x}{x^\varepsilon}=\kappa\cdot\left(\frac{\log z}z\right)^\delta\quad \text{with}\quad z=x^{\varepsilon/\delta}\quad \text{and}\quad \kappa=\left(\frac{\delta}{\varepsilon}\right)^\delta.
  $$
  Now, $z\to+\infty$ when $x\to+\infty$ because $\varepsilon/\delta\gt0$, and $\dfrac{\log u}u\to0$ when $u\to+\infty$.
- If $\delta\leqslant0$, one can compare the ratio to $\dfrac1{x^\varepsilon}$ for $x\geqslant\mathrm e$.