# How to find $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(\log n)^p}{n}$

Tags: limits, logarithms

How to solve $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(\log n)^p}{n}$$

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln^{\delta}(x)}{x^{\varepsilon}}=0 $, $\forall \delta\in\mathbb{R}, \varepsilon >0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148390/prove-that-lim-limits-x-to-infty-frac-ln-deltaxx-varepsilon-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\displaystyle\frac{(\log n)^p}{n}=p^p\cdot\left(\frac{\log k}k\right)^p$, where $k=n^{1/p}\to\infty$ when $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n = e^t$ and let $r = \lceil p \rceil+1$. Then $e^t > \dfrac{t^{r}}{r!}$, since $\displaystyle e^t = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{t^k}{k!}$. Hence, $$0 \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\log^p n}{n} = \lim_{t \to \infty} \dfrac{t^p}{e^t} < \lim_{t \to \infty} \dfrac{r!}{t^{r-p}} \leq \lim_{t \to \infty}\dfrac{r!}{t} = 0$$

Answer (score 2):

Replace $n$ by $2^n$ and take the limit to $\infty$.

Comment: That, assuming the sequence in $n$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle a(n) = \frac{\log^p n}{n}$. 
Notice that $\displaystyle \frac{a(n^2)}{a(n)} = \frac{2^p}{n}$.

Comment: hi. My first thought was to replace $n$ by $2^n$. Then you're done.

Comment: @Chris: There are many ways to go here! Another choice would be $n\to e^n$.

Comment: well, that way is already used by Marvis. :-)

Comment: Oops. Sometimes I am not a careful reader!

Comment: hehe. Neither do i all the time.

Comment: @Chris: Another interesting sum. I'll have a look.

Comment: Yes. It's a very beautiful sum.

Answer (score 0):

Apply $\,[p]+1\,$ times L'Hospital's rule to$\,\displaystyle{f(x):=\frac{\log^px}{x}}$:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log^px}{x}\stackrel{L'H}=\lim_{x\to\infty}p\frac{\log^{p-1}(x)}{x}\stackrel{L'H}=\lim_{x\to\infty}p(p-1)\frac{\log^{p-2}(x)}{x}\stackrel{L'H}=...\stackrel{L'H}=$$
$$\stackrel{L'H}=\lim_{x\to\infty}p(p-1)(p-2)...(p-[p])\frac{\log^{p-[p]-1}(x)}{x}=0$$
since $\,p-[p]-1<0\,$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148390/prove-that-lim-limits-x-to-infty-frac-ln-deltaxx-varepsilon-0

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(\log n)^p}{n}$.Taking $log$ both sides gives $\log A=\lim_{n\to\infty} (p\log \log n -\log n)=\lim_{\log n\to\infty} (p\log \log n -\log n) $.Take $y=1/\log n\implies \log A=\lim_{y\to0^+} (-p\log y -1/y) \implies \log A=\lim_{y\to0^+} \frac{-py\log y -1}{y}$.This limit surely goes to $-\infty$ and hence $\log A=-\infty\implies A=0$.Thus the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $p\leq 0$,then the result is $0$, which is trivial. We need consider the case when $p>0$ only. Let $ \alpha=\frac1 p>0$, then 
\begin{align*} \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln n}{n^{\alpha}}&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln(n+1)-\ln n}{(n+1)^{\alpha}-n^{\alpha}}&\text{Stolz}\\ &=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{n^{\alpha}\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\alpha}-1\right]}&\ln(1+x)\sim x,(1+x)^{\alpha}\sim \alpha x(x \to 0)\\ &=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{n^{\alpha}\cdot\frac{\alpha}{n}}\\ &=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{\alpha n^{\alpha}}\\ &=0 .\end{align*}
Therefore
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln^p n}{n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{\ln n}{n^{\alpha}}\right)^p=\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln n}{n^{\alpha}}\right)^p=0.$$