# Show that $n>(\log n)^k$ for sufficiently large values of $n$

Tags: limits, logarithms

How do you show that $n>(\log n)^k$, $k \in Z_+$ for sufficiently large values of $n$? This is a part of a larger problem that I want to solve, so I would be thankful if someone could show me the method.

Comment: Is $log^kn$ defined to be $\log(\log(\cdots n)\cdots))$ with $\log$ appearing $k$ times?

Comment: Here $\log^k n$ means the $k$-th power, or the iterated logarithm?

Comment: I meant $(\log n)^k$, I will edit my question to clarify.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164243/how-to-find-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-infty-frac-log-npn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=(\log{x})^k$. We now have $f'(x)=1$ and $g'(x)=k(\log{x})^{k-1}\frac{1}{x}$, and since $g'(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$, $f$ has to grow larger than $g$ eventually.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac n{(\log n)^k} =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac n{(k-1)(\log n)^{k-1}}$$

by L'Hôpital's rule. Now induct on $k$ to show $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac n{(\log n)^k} =\infty$$